# Reduce to Piecewise

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, piecewise

There are some similar posts on SE, but none of them seems to exactly address my issue.

I need to integrate a rather complicated function (over $x>1$) *separately* over two domains defined as `f1>0&&f2>0` (intersection of orange and blue) and `f1<0&&f2<0` (intersection of green and blue), **where the domains are shown for $y=3$.**

[image]

`Integrate` cannot handle this in a reasonable amount of time. Therefore, I want to first convert the integrand to a `Piecewise` function and then separately integrate over each interval. For instance

```
f1=x^2+(x-y)^2+z
f2=x^2+(x+y)^2+z
s=LogicalExpand[Reduce[f1>0&&f2>0&&x>1&&y>0&&z∈Reals,x]]
```

My question is, how can `s` be converted to a `Piecewise` function of `x`? The requirement is that the condition fields of `Piecewise` do not contain $x$ and that the value fields only contain conditions on $x$. In other words: the value of `Piecewise` determines the range of $x$-integration and the condition tells when this value can be used.

The actual function to integrate is

```
u = 1/x - Sqrt[f1 f2] /(2 x (x^2 + z)) Sign[f1] UnitStep[f1 f2]
```

It has a singularity at `x^2+z==0`, which should be understood in the `PrincipalValue` sense.

I kindly ask for the attention of community.

Comment: Why does `f1` and `f2` involve `z`? Is the first picture just a section of the domain?

Comment: @xzczd Yes, the picture depicts domains for a particular example of `y=3`.

Comment: Do you mean that, you first tried to make use of the `Boole[…]` or `∈reg` syntax of `Integrate` to calculate the integral but it doesn't finish in a reasonable time, so you decide to try the traditional way, and now you want to know how to find out the range of integration with _Mathematica_?

Comment: @xzczd Yes, you are right.

Comment: Can you provide the integrand under consideration? Have you tried to integrate over each piece of your LogicalExpand output using the Element syntax?

Comment: @CarlWoll Please, see edits. The value of the antiderivative at infinity is yet another tricky part. But I know for sure that the integral converges.

Comment: @CarlWoll I prefer to substitute the limits by hands because I known then what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

If I interpreted the question correctly, I think this does what you need.

```
OrList[HoldPattern[Or][args__]] := {args};
OrList[expr_] := {expr}

AndList[HoldPattern[And][args__]] := {args};
AndList[expr_] := {expr}

decomp = GenericCylindricalDecomposition[f1 > 0 && f2 > 0 && x > 1 && y > 0, {z, y, x}][[1]];

processed = OrList[BooleanConvert[decomp, "DNF"]];

pieces = With[{list = AndList[#]}, 
  {
    And @@ Select[list, !FreeQ[#, x]&], 
    And @@ Select[list, FreeQ[#, x]&]
  }
] & /@ processed;

Piecewise[pieces, True]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for a quick response! I checked your solution with `Block[{y = 3}, RegionPlot[Piecewise[pieces, True], {x, 1, 3}, {z, -6, -4}, PlotPoints -> 40]]` and `Block[{y = 3}, RegionPlot[f1 > 0 && f2 > 0, {x, 1, 3}, {z, -6, -4}, PlotPoints -> 40]]` and observed some differences at the upper left edge of the plot.

Comment: Ah, it looks like `Piecewise` is not a good proxy for `Or`. For `x == 1.1, y == 3, z == -4.6`, there are 2 *conditions* that are true and the first one happens to give a *value* of false. I'm trying to figure out how to fix this by using `PiecewiseExpand` with `"OrderlessConditions" -> Automatic`. I'll delete this answer if I'm not successful.

Comment: But I think the issue is that now the conditions will need to depend on x in order to know whether to move to the next one or not.

Comment: Yes, it is quite hard, I got a similar problem when doing simplifications manually. Please, do not remove your answer even if it is not complete. I never used `GenericCylindricalDecomposition` before. Really cool.